# How do I filter by a date range based on a dictionary value in python, otherwise filter a list by a dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionaries that look like this:

```
s_dates_dict = {17: datetime.date(2009,21,9,0,24), 19: datetime.datetime(2011,12,1,19,39,16), ....}  
e_dates_dict = {17: datetime.date(2010,25,9,10,24), 19: datetime.datetime(2012,1,11,17,39,16), ....}
```

I want to use these dictionaries to find the next record of type (A or B) after that date for each record.  So it seems that I would be best off creating a query similar to below:

```
next_record_list = Tasks.objects.filter(date__range(s_dates_dict,e_dates_dict), client__in=client_list, task_type__in=[A,B])
```

Whereby the dictionaries would cause a dynamically changing range to the pk referenced.  I haven't found anything suggesting this is possible or efficient, so I am guessing the next best would be creating a list by eliminating the date range filter and then iterating a dictionary of the oldest values using a for statement and cutting off iteration of each record at the date referenced in dates_dict.  But I haven't figured out a method to do this either.  Could I get some suggestions of how to do this, or a totally different better method?  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

client_list is a list of client objects.

Here is some of the models.py:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField

class Task(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(
                               'Client',
                               )
    task_type = models.ForeginKey(
                                  'Task_Type',
                                  )
    date = models.DateTimeField(
                                 default = datetime.now(),
                                 blank = True,
                                 null = True,
                                 )

class Task_Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a dynamically changing range to the pk referenced"?

Comment: maybe that is the wrong term, but I want to filter all records for client.pk=17 between (2009,21,9,0,24) and (2010,25,9,10,24).  Then for client.pk=19 between (2011,12,1,19,39,16) and (2012,1,11,17,39,16), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now. I am assuming `client_list` is actually a list of client objects. Someone may come up with a more efficient solution, but I would try something like this:

```
next_record = {}
for client in client_list:
    s = s_dates_dict[client.pk]
    e = e_dates_dict[client.pk]
    next_record[client.pk] = client.tasks_set.filter(date__range(s,e), task_type__in=[A,B])
```

This gives you a dict (`next_record`) where each key corresponds to a list of tasks. I am assuming there is a `ForeignKey` relationship between your `Tasks` and `Client` models.

Hopefully this works, if not, can you please post the code for your models?

Comment: I am getting: "TypeError: int() argument must be a string or number, not 'list'".  See above, I added some context for you.  Also, (sorry, I'm a bit of a newby to python), I had something similar that worked that used a for statement to loop through a method that queried each client record, but for large client lists took an excessive amount of time.  Is that the way this solution is also working?

Comment: I'm not sure where that error is coming from. Can you post a full stack trace? Yes, this method will make a separate query for each client, but I'm not sure there is any better way to do this. I would only worry about performance if/when it becomes an issue.

Comment: Apparently it was too late when I tried it last night, works fine now.  not sure why the issue earlier.  thanks.